jupyterlab 3 randomly does not run cells
I just updated my jupyterlab to Version 3.2.9.
Ever since, my run commands are randomly ignored. Sometimes, the execution seems to start and a star appears, but nothing happens, instead, the next cell is executed, if both were started in one go(leading to errors). When only running one cell, running again sometimes helps in these cases. Sometimes (in particular after a kernel interrupt), the code just won't execute anything any more (the brackets where a star or number should appear just stay blank).
I tried whether I could get something reproducible, but it all seems very random and I am at a loss. Is there anybody who has a good idea what I could check/try/... Has anybody ever seen this behavior?

Update: It now seems that this only happens if the following is executed at some point:
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
